# ¿ Como pasar los pametros de autenticación para las cabeceras de JWT?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

En el servicio lo estoy mandando así

```
_productLIST(token) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Authorization', token);
    return this._http.get(this._url + 'get-products', { headers: headers })
        .pipe(map((data: Response) => this.products = JSON.stringify(data)));
 }
```

En el componente lo implemento de la siguiente manera

```
listPro() {
 this._productService._productLIST(this.token).subscribe(data => {
   var pd = JSON.parse(data);
   this.products = pd.products;
   console.log(this.products);
},
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  });}
```

Pero me sale este error, la peticion no tiene la cabecera de autenticación.

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:8400/products/1", ok: false, …}
```

Alguna sugerencia sobre como podría hacerlo, Agradezco de antemano sus respuestas

Comment: creo que se solucionaria agregando el tipo de autenticacion `headers.set('Authorization', "JWT " +token);`

Answer (score 0):

Como son headers de autenticación y lo vas a usar supongo que en todas las peticiones al servidor, te recomiendo usar un interceptor, para que así por cada petición automáticamente el interceptor agregue el header.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

    @Injectable()
    export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            // Si usas Bearer
            // const currentUser = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN_KEY');
            if (this.token) {
                request = request.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: this.token, // `Bearer ${currentUser}`,
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                });
            }

            return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

                }
              }, (err: any) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                  if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
                    console.log('Credenciales erradas');
                  }
                }
              });
        }
    }
```

De esta forma el metodo del servicio quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
_productLIST() {
    return this._http.get(this._url + 'get-products')
        .pipe(map((data: Response) => this.products = JSON.stringify(data)));
 }
```